# Vertically aligning a Font Awesome icon inside a div along with an H1

Tags: css, font-awesome

Here's an HTML snippet:

```
<div class="source">
   <h1 class="source-text">dar</h1>
   <span class="sound">
      <i class="fa fa-volume-up pronounce"></i>
   </span>
</div>
```

And it renders as:

[image]

As you can see, the icon is *bottom-aligned* with the H1 tag. I need it center-aligned, instead. I have tried the following different ideas with my CSS:

**Adding negative padding to the span:**

```
.sound {
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    padding-top: -0.5em;
}
.pronounce {
    font-size: 2em !important;
}
```

**Adding negative padding to the icon:**

```
.sound {
    padding-left: 1.5em;
}
.pronounce {
    font-size: 2em !important;
    padding-top: -0.5em;
}
```

**Adding negative margin to the span:**

```
.sound {
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
}
.pronounce {
    font-size: 2em !important;
}
```

**Adding negative margin to the icon:**

```
.sound {
    padding-left: 1.5em;
}
.pronounce {
    font-size: 2em !important;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
}
```

I even tried `vertical-align: middle` on the span but the alignment is still unchanged. Any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may do it like this:

```
h1, span{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
.source > .sound {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

or

```
.source  { display: flex; }
.sound   { align-self: center; }
```

or

```
.source     { display: flex; }
.sound      { display: flex; align-self: center; }
.pronounce  { align-self: center; }
```

*(without seeing a working demo, it's hard to tell which option, if any, is best)*

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the css `line-height` property. [Link to explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp)

What you do is you take the `height` of the "wrapper" `<div>` of the `<h1>` and the `<i>` and you set the line height to equal to that height.

**Sample HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Some text</h1><i></i>
</div>
```

**Sample CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    height:200px;
    line-height:200px;
}
```

Hope this helps!